# Why is there no information being posted in email?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php">
                        <p class="contact-name">
                            <input id="contactName" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="contactName" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="contact-email">
                            <input id="contactEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="contactEmail" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="contact-message">
                            <textarea id="contactMessage" placeholder="Your Message" name="contactMessage" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <p class="contact-submit">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" id="contactSubmit">Submit</button>
                        </p>

                    </form>
```

That is the form html, below is the php

```
    <?php 

$name = $_POST['contactName'];
$email = $_POST['contactEmail'];
$message = $_POST['contactMessage'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "xxxx@vvvvv.co,";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$success=mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

    header('Location: http://www.website.com');

?>
```

I get the email but the user info they input doesn't show up in the email. I have used the same code before and I thought it worked but now this isn't so I am very confused. Thanks

Comment: add a `method="POST"` on your <form> tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for `form` element is the `method` `GET` and not `POST`. Thus, If you leave it empty it will act as if you used `method="get"`.

Add `method="post"` to your `form` element.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with method = "POST"

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="POST">
```

The default value is "GET" so your vars doesn't exists